# Контент на странице обновляется только при перезапуске сайта

Tags: html, django

Есть страница профиля человека, на которой размещаются все опубликованные этим человеком записи. Проблема в том, что если удалить/добавить запись, она удалится/добавится на всех других шаблонах, но останется на странице профиля автора. Решается это только полным перезапуском сайта.

views.py

```
class ProfileDetailView(DetailView):
    feed = Posts.objects.order_by('-date')
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'web/profile_detail_view.html'
    context_object_name = 'detailprofile'

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=feed, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['feed'] = object_list
        return context
```

models.py

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField('Название', max_length=50)
    desc = models.CharField('Описание', max_length=300)
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',default='images/user.png')
    audiofile = models.FileField(upload_to='audio/',default='audio/default.mp3')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

html

```
        {% for post in feed %}
            {% if post.author.username == detailprofile.user.username %}
                        <img src="{{ post.cover.url }}" alt="">
                        <h3 class="song_title">{{ post.title }}</h3>
                        <h3 class="song_author">{{ post.author.username }}</h3>
                        <audio controls src="{{ post.audiofile.url }}" class='song_audio'></audio>
                        <h5 class="song_date"> {{ post.date }} </h5>
                        <h3 class="song_desc"> {{ post.desc }}</h3>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Поля класса инициализируются в момент запуска кода. Вы создали поле `feed`, в которое поместили записи из базы **в момент запуска кода**, а не в момент получения запроса на сайт, вот они там и остаются висеть до следующего запуска кода

Comment: А ещё вы написали `object_list=feed` в объявлении функции, и таким образом эти записи остаются навсегда висеть в качестве значения по умолчанию в аргументах функции

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо, исправил и все заработало!